# select: Invalid argument on ssh localforward

Tags: ssh, python-requests, python-asyncio, file-descriptor, ssh-tunnel

I have a config file with localforward settings as below

LocalForward 8443 remoteserver.com:8443

After I ssh into it in debug mode and start sending many requests to remote server, I see the below lines

```
debug1: channel 1017: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 1018
debug1: channel 1: free: port listener, nchannels 1017
debug1: channel 2: free: port listener, nchannels 1016
debug1: channel 3: free: port listener, nchannels 1015
debug1: channel 4: free: port listener, nchannels 1014
debug1: channel 5: free: port listener, nchannels 1013
debug1: channel 6: free: port listener, nchannels 1012
debug1: channel 7: free: port listener, nchannels 1011
debug1: channel 8: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8443 for remotserver.com port 8443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 49991 to 127.0.0.1 port 8443, nchannels 1010
debug1: channel 9: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8443 for remoteserver.com port 8443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 49992 to 127.0.0.1 port 8443, nchannels 1009
.
.

debug1: channel 1016: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8443 for remoteserver.com port 8443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51113 to 127.0.0.1 port 8443, nchannels 2
debug1: channel 1017: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8443 for remoteserver.com port 8443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51114 to 127.0.0.1 port 8443, nchannels 1
select: Invalid argument
```

and the SSH breaks/exits with 'select: Invalid argument'. I could see the nchannels decreased till 1 and it failed to make any more channels. Below is the output of 'ulimit -aH' in my machine.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524288
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

May I know what configuration that sets the number of channels limit to ~1024 or so and how can I increase it to send 10000+ requests from my machine asynchronously.

Here's the python code to send these requests

```
async def async_fun(self, loop):
    for record in enumerate(record_list): #10000+ records 
        task = loop.run_in_executor(
                concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3),
                self._fun,
                record,
                )
        futures.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*futures, return_exceptions=True)
```

Comment: You are creating a **new executor** for each record, which means that they all run in parallel, not just 3 at a time as appears to be your intention. This might be bringing the server to its knees. Try changing the code [like this](https://pastebin.com/8rfkWC3s) and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, one has to wonder why use `asyncio` in the first place if you are doing all the work using sync functions in a thread pool. Consider switching to an API that actually makes use of asyncio, such as [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of `requests`.